# For which value of n is $1{\underbrace{0..0}_n}1\underbrace{0..0}_n1$ divisible by 37?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

The solution given in the book is n=0mod3 or 1mod3 but I could not understand  the  approach please help.

Comment: Have you checked the cases $n=0,1,2$ by hand? If so, please include such calculations into your question body (click the edit button). You can build from those cases using the observations in my hint/answer.

Comment: And... Welcome to MSE. As a friendly piece of advice I recommend that you read [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). This is basically so that you avoid surprises, if your questions look too much like attempts to outsource homework. The current version of your question may fall short of the standards of many regulars.

Comment: If there is an approach given in your book that you don't understand, **tell us what that approach is**. Otherwise any answers you get will be based on pure guesswork about what it is you don't understand. That's a pointless waste of resources when _you have the information we need_ but just coyly insist on keeping it a secret -- for which purpose?

Comment: @HenningMakholm  In the book it is given that $x^{2}+x+1=111$ if x=10 , $x^{2(n+1)}+x^{n+1}+1=1{\underbrace{0...0}_n}1{\underbrace{0...0}_n}1$. The number is divisible by 3 since the sum of the  is 3. Therefore n=0mod3 or n=1mod3. I cannot understand how did they form the second  polynomial equation .

Comment: @Pulsar: You're right, that looks pretty opaque to me too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because $37\cdot27=999$ we have $10^3\equiv1\pmod{37}$ and consequently $10^{3a}\equiv1\pmod{37}$ for all $a$. We also have $37\cdot3=111$, so $10^0+10^1+10^2\equiv0\pmod{37}$. Can you take it from here?